# how to convert map to Vec2f in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, stl

I have converted the map into vector but one [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5xlH.jpg) occured. Ihave been trying to solve it for hours but no luck.

"Error (active) E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=cv::Vec2f, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list"

```
map<int,vector<Vec2f>>::iterator itr = segmented.begin();
vector<Vec2f> segments;
int i = 0;
while (itr != segmented.end())
{   
    segments.push_back(itr->second);

    itr++;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the types, in your case `itr->second` it's a `std::vector<Vec2f>` not a `Vec2f`, so you can't push_back a vector to another vector, you can use insert to do that:

```
segments.insert(segments.end(), itr->second.begin(), itr->second.end());
```

or if you use C++11 you can use the more generic `std::begin` and `std::end`:

```
segments.insert(std::end(segments), std::begin(itr->second), std::end(itr->second));
```

Note: if you can use [reserve()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) on the vector with the total number of elements before you do the loop with inserts, to avoid multiple re-allocations of your vector.